# How to connect via ssh and use gcc on target?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh, gcc

I would like to do two things automatically within a bash script:

1. Connect via ssh to my target.
2. Execute gcc.

My script looks like this:

```
(
        echo "cd myfolder"
        echo "gcc -o mybin main.c"
        sleep 5
) | ssh target@192.168.1.2
```

The script works pretty fine and compiles the source successfully.
But I can't see the output of gcc on the terminal.

What do I need to change to see the output of gcc, when I run the script?

Answer (score 2):

You can put your gcc command right after ssh command, such as

```
ssh target@ip "gcc -o mybin main.c && ./mybin"
```

will compile main.c in your target's home folder and if compiling is successful, run "mybin" to see output, if there is any output of this program.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not show any output of gcc, too.

Comment: @eDeviser, from my test, if gcc is successful without any error, there is no output, you can add some error to your codes to test gcc output, or add "-v" option to see verbose output - ssh target@ip "gcc -v -o mybin main.c"

Comment: Oh, you are right,... well okay, with the -v option my script in my question is working fine, too! Thanks. Now I know a new way of processing my script in one line.

Comment: Well, but the output of './mybin' is not shown, too...

Comment: @eDeviser maybe you forget to run it? At least from your original script, it does not run your mybin; There is no difference between gcc output or your program's output, unless you program does not show anything on terminal. My test program is just printf("something\n").

Comment: Yes you are right. If the test program is just printing something and then terminates, the output is visible. But my program will just stop after user intearaction. Just insert while(1); after your printf and see, there is no output anymore.